# Iteratively remove file type

Tags: linux

I'm trying to delete the files that visual sourcesafe inserts into various folders. It's this file:

```
 vssver2.scc
```

Since I have many nested folders, I'd like to do this recursively from the parent folder.  What would the linux code be to delete all files with .scc extension? (I'm on a mac).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for them and remove:

```
find . -name "*.scc" -exec rm {} +
```

To make sure you are going to delete the correct files, you can replace the `rm` with `ls` so that it will show these files.

Also, you can replace `find .` with `find /your/path` to indicate the exact path from which you want to remove. With `find .` it will start from the current path.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name ".scc" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```